# Failed to remove file Permission denied clean cache

Tags: symfony

** Symfony version(s) affected**: 4.4.X
symfony/console": "4.4.*"

** Description **
We faced the issue with permission system when we clean the cache.

```
# Base stage
FROM php:7.4.15-fpm-alpine
USER www-data
CMD ["php-fpm"]

entrypoint --> bin/console cache:clear
```

** How to reproduce **
Change the owner of container ROOT --> www-data
run bin/console cache:clear in entrypoint

```
php_1             | In Filesystem.php line 184:
php_1             |                                                                                
php_1             |   Failed to remove file "/srv/api/var/cache/prod/ContainerTcfhxsf/srcApp_Kern  
php_1             |   elProdContainer.php": unlink(/srv/api/var/cache/prod/ContainerTcfhxsf/srcAp  
php_1             |   p_KernelProdContainer.php): Permission denied                                
php_1             |                                                                                
php_1             | 
php_1             | cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers]
```

**Possible Solution**
i try this command in my docker file but nothing work , i don't want to use chmod 777 or umask 000 instead

```
RUN mkdir -p var/cache/prod var/log
# permission denied php
RUN umask 022 var/cache/prod
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/api/var/cache /srv/api/var/log
RUN setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:www-data:rwX var intl config
RUN setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:www-data:rwX var intl config
```

Comment: the problem usually exists, if someone runs the file-creating/modifying commands both outside and inside docker, which especially includes calls to composer (since it'll run symfony console commands as well). the user running commands inside the container should match the fpm-user. neither symfony nor composer commands should be run outside docker in these setups. (or you match the fpm-user-id to your user-id)

Comment: hello Jakumi thanks for your helps It solve my issue. I put the composer step in entrypoint docker file after the USER www-data